# Mercurial hg rebase detach?

Tags: mercurial

My situation:

```
develop: [A]->[E]
            \
feature:    [C]->[D]
```

My goal:

```
develop: [A]->[E]
            \
feature:    [E]->[C]->[D]
```

What's happening instead:

```
develop: [A]
            \
feature:    [C]->[D]->[E]
```

As I understand [the documentation](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension), running `hg rebase` should **detach** my local changes `[C]->[D]`, apply `[E]` and re-attach `[C]->[D]`. Obviously, I'm misunderstanding something.

Can anybody help me? (I'm using `2.6.1`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are rebasing `E` onto `D`. Instead, you should update to `B` and rebase it onto `E` (if using TortoiseHg), or run

```
hg update D
hg rebase --dest E --base D
```

or

```
hg rebase --source B --dest E
```

There are plenty examples at the documentation page you're referring to.

Update: to keep branch names in the changesets, specify `--keepbranches`.

Comment: The reasons why I ask here is because the provided examples don't work for me (probably because I'm doing something wrong). `hg rebase --source B --dest E` creates two develop branches. The other way around it creates two feature branches. I think the meaning of rebasing is to not create branches that have to be merged afterwards, but to create straight history lines. Any idea?

Comment: I have just created a test repository with five revisions (0=A, 1=B, 2=C, 3=D, 4=E (parent 0)), and executed `hg rebase --source 1 --dest 4` which gave a single A-E-B-C-D branch. Maybe you are specifying the revisions incorrectly?

Comment: I'll try that too and let you know, thanks already for your help.

Comment: I'm still not getting it. Here's exactly what I did. It seems to me that I don't understand something that must be fundamental: hg init; echo -e "[extensions]\nrebase=" > .hg/hgrc; echo "Test test" > testfile.txt; hg add; hg commit -m "Commit 1"; hg branch feature; echo "some change" >> testfile.txt; hg commit -m "Commit 2"; hg up default; echo "Test test 2" > newfile.txt; hg add; hg commit -m "Commit 3"; hg up feature; hg rebase --source 2 --dest 1; # Expected: "Commit 3" -> "Commit 2"; # Actual: "Commit 2" -> "Commit 3";  When I change `--source` and `--dest`, my `feature` branch disappears.

Comment: So, you Commit1 is revision 0, Commit2 is 1, and Commit3 is 2. Rebasing with `--source 2 --dest 1` puts Commit3 on top of Commit 2.  That seems sensible. The other way around removes `feature` branch which also seems sensible as commits are planted on top of `default` branch and you don't specify `--keepbranches`. I'm sorry, most likely I haven't understood what you want. Do you want to put all the commits into `feature` branch instead of `default` branch, but keep the commits order as if `feature` branch was rebased upon `default`?

Comment: I'd like to detach all the changes I have made on `feature` (`[C] and [D]`), update it to the latest changes from `develop` (`[E]`), and then re-attach my changes back again, on top of what has come in from `develop`. I'm still on `feature`, because it's not finished yet, but my branch is up to date (meaning changes from `develop` are there, "below" my changes `[C] and [D]`). I hope it's more clear now... :-)

Comment: I have updated my graffiti above to illustrate my goal better.

Comment: That changes a lot. Commit `[B]` has disappeared :) So, just to make it clear: do you want the commit `[E]` to present in your repository twice - in both branches? I'd advise against that, or you will have problems merging the `feature` back into `develop`. Also, it's unlikely that `rebase` performs the changes you've shown at the last scheme: rebase doesn't duplicate changesets. Usually, the workflow is the following: rebase `feature` branch on top of latest changes from stable (`develop`) branch. The commit `[E]` should be the last in the `develop` branch, and `[C]` should reside upon it.

Comment: I mean what you will have with rebase is `[A (develop)] -> [E (develop)] -> [C (feature)] -> [D (feature)]` which still allows to commit into both branches (the first commit into `develop` will create a new head). Well, if you REALLY want to duplicate `[E]` into the `feature` branch consider using `graft` command (but it would compilcate things).

Comment: You're right, it didn't duplicate it (I corrected it). Hmmm then what would you recommend to do to keep my `feature` branch up to date (without "destroying" the `develop` branch)?

Comment: My recommendation is to rebase `[C]` on top of `[E]` with `--keepbranches`. In this way, your `feature` branch will base on up-to-date changes from `develop` branch. And `develop` branch will still exist. In fact, the `develop` branch is not changed at all, it remains untouched, and that's how it should be. You may not see the `develop`'s head as `[C]` sits on top of it, but don't be confused, the branch exists, and you can always perform `hg up develop` and then commit into it.